# angular 2 ng-xi18n gets error when importing external module

Tags: angular

I am trying to generate message.xlf file using angular ng-xi18n tool but I get the following error :

```
 $ ./node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n

Error: Unexpected value 'Select2Component' declared by the module 'AppModule'
```

If I run the application using ng serve I get no error. I saw this question asked in another place but didn't get a solution.

Has anyone managed to solve this?

Thanks.